# Como ordenar array estruturas baseado no rank das musicas?

Tags: c, struct

O rank do código ta indo em ordem crescente porem os demais não trocam as posições juntamente com o rank, como faço para as posições das musicas e estilos irem juntamente com o código ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct musica{
char nome[100];
char estilo[100];
int rank;
};

typedef struct musica Musica;

int main (void){
int i,j,aux;
Musica a[8];

setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

for (i=0; i<4; i++){

    printf ("Nome da música: ");
    gets (a[i].nome);

    printf ("Estilo musical: ");
    gets (a[i].estilo);

    printf ("Ranking da música: ");
    scanf ("%d",&a[i].rank);

    printf ("\n\n");

    getchar();
}
//RANKING DIGITADO DESORDENADO
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf ("RANK %d\t%s\t%s\t\n", a[i].rank, a[i].nome, a[i].estilo);
}
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        for (j=i+1; j<8; j++){
            if (a[i].rank > a[j].rank){
                aux = a[i].rank;
                a[i].rank = a[j].rank;
                a[j].rank = aux;
                }
            }
        }
printf ("\n");
//RANKING ORDEM
for (i=0; i<4; i++){
    printf ("RANK %d\t%s\t%s\t\n", a[i].rank, a[i].nome, a[i].estilo);
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está no *swap* dos valores do vetor, que apenas troca o `rank` de cada elemento a ordenar. Para que a troca seja feita como um todo pode fazer a troca entre elementos da estrutura diretamente:

```
Musica temp; //variável temporária para troca do tipo Musica

for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<4; j++) {
        //--------^ 4 e não 8
        if (a[i].rank > a[j].rank) {
            //trocas agora todas feitas com a variável temp
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

[Exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/A18bke)

Apesar de já funcionar esta solução é bastante fraca a nível de eficiência pois cada vez que atribui uma estrutura a outra:

```
temp = a[i];
```

Obriga à copia de todos os bytes de um elemento para outro.

### Utilizando ponteiros

Se a quantidade de musicas crescer um pouco a eficiência da ordenação pode ser posta em causa devido à quantidade excessiva de copias feitas em memoria. Um dos vários pontos de resolução deste problema é a utilização de ponteiros, pois pode fazer a troca entre elementos apenas modificando o ponteiro sem ter de copiar os bytes todos entre elementos.

Isto tem implicações pois torna necessário alterar a forma como o vetor está a ser utilizado no resto do programa, assim como implica alocar as musicas dinamicamente com `malloc`:

```
int main (void) {
    int i,j;
    Musica *a[8]; //vetor de ponteiros

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        a[i] = malloc(sizeof(Musica)); //criação do elemento da estrutura
        printf ("Nome da música: ");
        gets (a[i]->nome); //acesso com -> por partir de ponteiro

        printf ("Estilo musical: ");
        gets (a[i]->estilo); //acesso com -> por partir de ponteiro

        printf ("Ranking da música: ");
        scanf ("%d",&(a[i]->rank)); //acesso com -> por partir de ponteiro

        printf ("\n\n"); 
        getchar();
    }

    //RANKING DIGITADO DESORDENADO
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf ("RANK %d\t%s\t%s\t\n", a[i]->rank, a[i]->nome, a[i]->estilo);
        //---------------------------------^-----------^-----------^
    }

    Musica *temp; //agora cada elemento é um ponteiro

    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        for (j=i+1; j<4; j++) {
            if (a[i]->rank > a[j]->rank) {
                //agora estas trocas são trocas de ponteiros, apenas indicando que
                //estão a apontar para elementos diferentes
                temp = a[i];
                a[i] = a[j];
                a[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    //RANKING ORDEM
    for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
        printf ("RANK %d\t%s\t%s\t\n", a[i]->rank, a[i]->nome, a[i]->estilo);
    }
}
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/FxlTEb)

### Quicksort

Se quiser considerar a eficiência da ordenação de uma forma séria deve trocar o algoritmo de ordenação que está a utilizar, neste caso o *Bubblesort*, por um mais eficiente como por exemplo o *Quicksort*.

Para o *Quicksort* irá haver uma função de ordenação principal que divide o array em duas partes e ordena cada sub-parte recursivamente utilizando a mesma função. O elemento onde divide é chamado o *pivot* e a os elementos inferiores são colocados à esquerda dele e os superiores à direita. Este processo chama-se particionar.

Exemplo de implementação:

```
int particao(Musica *musicas[], int baixo, int alto){
    Musica *pivot = musicas[baixo], *temp;
    int i = baixo - 1, j = alto + 1;

    while (1){
        do { i = i + 1; } while (musicas[i]->rank < pivot->rank);
        do { j = j - 1; } while (musicas[j]->rank > pivot->rank);

        if (i >= j) return j;

        temp = musicas[i];
        musicas[i] = musicas[j];
        musicas[j] = temp;
    }
}

void quicksort(Musica *musicas[], int baixo, int alto){
    if (baixo < alto){
        int pivot = particao(musicas, baixo, alto);
        quicksort(musicas, baixo, pivot);
        quicksort(musicas, pivot+1, alto);
    }
}
```

Agora no `main` apenas precisa de chamar a função passando os limites de ordenação:

```
quicksort(a, 0, 3);
```

[Veja também este exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/DNHh5H)

### Ordenando com `qsort`

Na verdade o próprio C já tem funções de ordenação, sendo uma delas o [`qsort`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/). Embora o nome sugira o algoritmo quicksort a especificação não indica que tenha que ser algoritmo o utilizado, o que dá margem para implementações diferentes. Normalmente as implementações tendem para algoritmos com complexidade de O(nlogn) que dão eficiência ao nível do quicksort.

Para utilizar o `qsort` tem de primeiro construir uma função de comparação dos elementos:

```
int compararMusicas(const void* musica1, const void* musica2){
    Musica* m1 = *((Musica**)musica1);
    Musica* m2 = *((Musica**)musica2);

    return m1->rank-m2->rank;
}
```

A função de comparação recebe como parâmetro um ponteiro para cada elemento do vetor. Se cada elemento é um `Musica*` e por isso um ponteiro já, os parâmetros vão ser `Musica**`, ou seja ponteiros para ponteiros.

Tendo esta função basta apenas chamar o `qsort` com os parâmetros corretos:

```
qsort(a, 4, sizeof(Musica*), compararMusicas);
```

Estes parametros são:

- `a` - array a ordenar
- `4` - quantidade de elementos a ordenar
- `sizeof(Musica*)` - tamanho de cada elemento
- `compararMusicas` função de comparação dos elementos

[Veja este ultimo exemplo no Ideone](https://ideone.com/NN5naL)