# Ordenar strings num vetor de structs em C

Tags: c, string

Estou tentando ordenar em ordem alfabética strings em um vetor de strings em uma struct, porém por algum motivo os nomes ficam bugado

```
#define TV 10
#define TC 100

typedef struct ficha {
    char nome[TC];
    int dependentes;
    float salario;
    int atendimentos;
    char email[TC];
} FICHA;

...

void ordenarDadosString(FICHA usuario[TV], int qntdUsuarios)
{
    int i, trocou, ls = qntdUsuarios - 1;
    char aux[TC];
    aux[TC - 1] = '\0';
    do {
        trocou = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < ls; i++) {
            if(strcmp(usuario[i].nome, usuario[i + 1].nome) > 0) {
                strcpy(usuario[i].nome, aux);
                strcpy(usuario[i + 1].nome, usuario[i].nome);
                strcpy(aux, usuario[i].nome);
                trocou = 1;
            }
        }
        ls--;
    } while(trocou);
}
```

Aqui uma print do que aparece ao tentar ordenar http://prntscr.com/li0wuw
Aqui o código completo, caso ajude https://pastebin.com/pBjSEUGZ

Comment: Ordenar `structs` com base num campo da `struct` é isso ?

Comment: sim, exatamente isso, no caso eu consegui fazer isso com variaveis int, mas com strings da erro na hora de fazer a troca, não sei pq

Comment: [Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/253763/como-ordenar-tudo-baseado-no-rank-das-musicas/253773) tem basicamente o que pretende apesar da comparação ser feita num campo inteiro em vez de numa string. Na pratica muda muito pouco mesmo, apenas tem de usar o `strcmp` em vez de comparar diretamente

Comment: consegui, tava tentando entender como era no exemplo que me mandaram, obrigado pessoal